# Problem with ggplot scaling y-axis on graph (growth rate)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, rate, yaxis

i have the following problem (see graph) This is my code:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
nba2plot <- ggplot(wdata, aes(x=logBIPproKopf_start, y=Dwachstumsrate2, color=Bundesland, group = Bundesland)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
  #scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
  
  #fullrange=TRUE
  
nba2plot + 
  ylab("Durchschnittliche Wachstumsrate 1992-2021") + xlab("Log-BIP pro Kopf (1992)") +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = Bundesländer),
                   box.padding   = 0.35, 
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50')+
theme_classic()
```

My excel data sheet:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I´ve tried with ylim() and with scale_y_continous to change my y-axis scale into 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 steps. Unfortunately, it does not work. The error code for scale_y_continous is that the growth rate on y-axis is discrete. Has anyone an idea, how to change the y-scale?

Thank you in advance.

> dput(wdata)
> structure(list(Bundesländer = c("Baden-Württemberg", "Bayern",
> "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Bremen", "Hamburg", "Hessen", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Niedersachsen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Thüringen"
> ), Durch_Wachstumsrate = c(0.00214, 0.00243, 0.00238, 0.00414,
> 0.0019, 0.0019, 0.00192, 0.00419, 0.00225, 0.00198, 0.00219,
> 0.00193, 0.00432, 0.00434, 0.00195, 0.00445), logBIPproKopf_start = c(10.135063,
> 10.088054, 9.985669, 9.175367, 10.251523, 10.537632, 10.196896,
> 9.154323, 9.914183, 10.02792, 9.934173, 9.929703, 9.191263, 9.122386,
> 9.908949, 9.097269), Bundesland = c("Alt", "Alt", "Alt", "Neu",
> "Alt", "Alt", "Alt", "Neu", "Alt", "Alt", "Alt", "Alt", "Neu",
> "Neu", "Alt", "Neu"), Dwachstumsrate1 = c(0.0263, 0.0299, 0.0273,
> 0.0419, 0.0201, 0.0243, 0.0227, 0.0372, 0.0256, 0.0213, 0.025,
> 0.0169, 0.0391, 0.0348, 0.0233, 0.0382), Dwachstumsrate2 = c("0.0231",
> "0.0259", "0.0252", "0.0420", "0.0206", "0.0210", "0.0205", "0.0425",
> "0.0236", "0.0208", "0.0230", "0.0204", "0.0441", "0.0439", "0.0202",
> "0.0450"), BIPproKopf_start = c(25212, 24054, 21173, 9656, 28326,
> 37708, 26820, 9455, 20215, 22650, 20623, 20531, 9811, 9158, 20110,
> 8931)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
> -16L))

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO @amg9889! It is always recommended to include some sample data in your question, so that others can reproduce your example. You could use the `dput()` function for doing this. However, according to the error message, I guess that there is an issue regarding the data type. Your variable on the y-axis does not seem to be formatted as a numeric variable but without some reproducible data it is hard to say.

Comment: Hi fbeese, sorry, i am new here :)

Comment: i have added the dput() material :)

Comment: Dwachstumsrate2 is currently character data and not numeric, so it is being treated like names spelled in numbers, not as numbers. That's why it's showing every single value on the y axis and can't log transform them. Run `wdat$Dwachstumsrate2 <- as.numeric(wdat$Dwachstumsrate2)` to fix it before you plot, or better yet, fix that at the import stage.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon, this was the solution!